# How to trigger task using spring cloud stream and pass white listed properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have create the stream as below

1.stream create SampleClaimInjestTask --definition "triggertask --triggertask.uri=file://D:/ClaimReportBatch/target/ClaimReportBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar   --trigger.fixed-delay=60 --triggertask.environment-properties=spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/scdf,spring.datasource.username=postgres,spring.datasource.password=postgres | task-launcher-local --authentication-token-u-r-l=http://10.73.122.140:9040/api/authenticate --rest-post-api-u-r-l=http://10.73.122.140:9040/api/claim-report-transactions --processed-file-folder=D:/processed --csv-file-path=D:/local-files --json-config-path=D:/remote-files"

2.stream deploy --name SampleClaimInjestTask

3.Stream SampleClaimInjestTask deployed successfully

4 task-launcher trigger the task.But those properties not set in BatchConfigurationProperties.class

Error log:
018-10-18 15:32:12.744 ERROR 9360 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readClaimReportCSVFilesJob' defined in class path resource [com/ev/fincloud/fdp/ClaimReportBatch/config/ClaimReportBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'readClaimReportCSVFilesJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileProcessingStep' defined in class path resource [com/ev/fincloud/fdp/ClaimReportBatch/config/ClaimReportBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'fileProcessingStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiResourceItemReader' defined in class path resource [com/ev/fincloud/fdp/ClaimReportBatch/config/ClaimReportBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader]: Factory method 'multiResourceItemReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.19.RELEASE]

Comment: Can you describe what causes NPE in the stack trace? Also, what `BatchConfigurationProperties` are you referring to? Is this something specific to your custom application?

Comment: BatchConfigurationProperties.java is spring configuration properties.

Comment: BatchConfigurationProperties.java is spring configuration properties for that task .When i was passing  in command line arguments not set in BatchConfigurationProperties

Comment: For any explicit configuration properties class, you need to add them in the `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties`. For more info on this, you can refer here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting